# KMM error Command PhaseScriptExecution failed

Tags: xcode, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to run iosApp of KMM project in Xcode,  but i am getting error Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

```
export variant\=normal /bin/sh -c /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iosApp-ftrrlcszyheexqhbvoqhhryktogx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Previews/iosApp/Intermediates.noindex/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Script-7555FFB5242A651A00829871.sh
The operation couldn't be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I have java installed, and android app is running well from androidStudio,  I tried solution mentioned in this [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-43240). but no success

Comment: check out [kdoctor](https://github.com/Kotlin/kdoctor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve this issue. I simply set up the Java path in my Xcode, Just navigate to

```
XCode -> Setting -> Locations -> Custom Paths
```

[image]